# TestCafe EC2 Network logs

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are "successfully" running our gherkin-testcafe build on ec2 headless against chromium. The final issue we are dealing with is that at a certain point in the test a CTA button is showing ...loading instead of Add to Bag, presumably because a service call that gets the status of the product, out of stock, in stock, no longer carry, etc. is failing. The tests work locally of course and we have the luxury of debugging locally opening chrome's dev env and inspecting the network calls etc. But all we can do on the ec2 is take a video and see where it fails. Is there a way to view the logs of all the calls being made by testcafe's proxy browser so we can confirm which one is failing and why? We are using. 
 const rlogger = RequestLogger(/.*/, {
logRequestHeaders: true,
logResponseHeaders: true
});

to log our headers but not getting very explicit reasons why calls are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe uses the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module to perform internal logging functionality. So, in order to view the TestCafe proxy logs, you can set the `DEBUG` environment variable in the following manner:

```
export DEBUG='hammerhead:*'
```